# E: Type '“ndeb' is not known on line 7 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt, firefox

I want to install Firefox, so I copy and pasted this command in terminal:

```
echo -e “\ndeb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main” | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
```

But I got an error:

```
E: Type '“ndeb' is not known on line 7 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

Those quotes (`“\ndeb...`) are Unicode "pretty" quotes, not the normal `""`. Therefore, `echo -e` didn't work as expected, since bash, without quotes, took `\n` and converted it to `n`, which `echo` printed as-is.

Delete that line:

```
sed -i '/mozilla/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And now run that command with normal quotes:

```
echo -e "\ndeb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list > /dev/null
```

Though I don't know why you want do this. Firefox is installed by default, and even if it wasn't, is available in the official repositories, and well-updated. Just do `sudo apt-get install firefox`.